# How to extract the number 5005733989 from the string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to extract this number 5005733989 from this string "employee-process-5005733989-19874"

Comment: is it always the third segment ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution, but we can do this using the base string functions `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(col,
                 CHARINDEX('-', col, CHARINDEX('-', col) + 1) + 1,
                 CHARINDEX('-', col, CHARINDEX('-', CHARINDEX('-', col) + 1)) -
                     CHARINDEX('-', CHARINDEX('-', col) + 1) + 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'employee-process-5005733989-19874' AS col
)
```

Comment: You need to learn `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @Charlieface I could counter your comment by saying that SQL Server needs to learn regex `:-)`

Comment: Difference is: the one is easier and far more likely to happen :-) Come on, just rewrite it, it's not difficult

Answer (score 0):

Using **STRING SPLIT** also we can achieve the Same.

Use top 1,to find the 1st number Segment alone.

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX)='employee-process-5005733989-19874'

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@STR,'-')
WHERE value like '%[0-9]%'
```

Expected Result:

```
5005733989
```

Comment: Note that `STRING_SPLIT` generates an _unordered_ set of tuples.  Your use of `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` clause is therefore not guaranteed to behave as you expect.